# Filemaker Pro table with only one record

Tags: filemaker

I have a FileMaker Pro 13 database. I have a table "Company Info" where I want to store the company name, address, phone number etc. This information will be used on all layouts and reports to identify the name of company who owns the business. I only want this table to have a maximum of one record.

How do I do this?

Is there a setting somewhere that says the table is a single-record table only?

Or will I have to handle this via a script on the layout that I have to maintain the "Company Info" table?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set custom privileges on that table (make sure you don't do it for *all* tables!). Go to the custom record privileges dialog box, choose the table and remove the 'Create' privilege for new records.

Answer (score 1):

[All Access] accounts could still create new records if you use a privilege set to restrict who can add records. Another option is to use validation on a field in this table which can never pass, and show a custom validation message. Try this:

- Auto-enter calc of 1
- Uncheck "Allow user to override during data entry"
- Validate by calculation: False
- Display custom message if validation fails: "There can only be one record in this table"

Might be a good idea to make sure people don't delete the record now :) (privilege sets might be your best bet here)